# How to get dynamic segment id inside a hook in the Ember REST adapter

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, adapter

Assuming we have URL like `/posts/awesome-post/comments` (which is `/posts/1/comments` which is `/posts/:post_id/comments`)

We have **comment** adapter

```
export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  pathForType(modelName) {
    // how to get :post_id here?
  }
});
```

How to get Awesome Post's id (:post_id) inside `pathForType` hook in the comment adapter?

Comment: You can't. (Or at least you _might_ be able to, but I would **highly** recommend against it.) Would you mind elaborating on your use case a little bit? There's probably a better way to do what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @GJK I have very non-standard API, so I'm using adapters and serializers to convert JSON API into format that Ember REST Adapter expects. In order to retrieve comments to particular post I need to make a call not to `/comments` but to `post_id/comments`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You likely want to use [store.find](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html#method_find) in this scenario. So in your adapter, override the [buildURL](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTAdapter.html#method_buildURL) method like this:

```
export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    buildURL(modelName, id, snapshot, requestType, query) {
        const postId = query.postId;

        if (postId) {
            // Make your own URL
        } else {
            return this._super.apply(this, arguments);
        }
    }
});
```

Then you can fetch the comments like this:

```
this.store.find('comment', { postId: id });
```

Comment: `modelName, id, snapshot, requestType, query` gives me `comment null null findAll undefined`

Comment: What version of Ember-Data are you using? (I should have asked that first.)

Comment: DEBUG: Ember      : 2.3.0
DEBUG: Ember Data : v2.3.0

Comment: The two `null`s make sense. Are you passing an object to your `store.find` call? Also, that method is likely being called more than once, so make sure you're debugging the correct invocation of it.

Comment: The method is called only once. I'm not passing any object to store.find, only this: `model() {
  return this.modelFor('post').get('comments');
}`

Comment: OK, that's slightly different. In that case you'll might have to override [urlForFindHasMany](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTAdapter.html#method_urlForFindHasMany). I honestly don't know very much about changing that behavior, it's been a long time since I've used Ember-Data. I'd have to dig deeper to find out.